# Adding my facebook application to my profile; my profile not showing up as a page to add to

Tags: facebook

Exactly as the title says:

I'm trying to add my facebook application to my profile; but my profile does not show up as a page to add to via the facebook app page.  It's an app that shows as a tab.

I can add it to my other pages, just not my own profile, any idea?

Comment: You could accept the answer from @Misty-Lackie if it answered your question. It doesn't cost you anything.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a Facebook page app that allows you to add tabs to your Facebook pages. If that is the case, you won't be able to add it to your personal profile.

Comment: It's my own built app.  Ahh, for some reason I thought you could add apps to your personal profiles.  Welp, that answers that, thanks!

Comment: You were once able to do this but Facebook did away with it last year. See http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/10/08/facebook-to-begin-removing-third-party-user-profile-tabs-on-november-3rd/